# Material-UI - Can I selectively enable Button ripple?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I know I can turn off all ripples by putting this in the theme object:

```
components: {
  MuiButtonBase: {
    defaultProps: {
      disableRipple: true,
    },
  },
},
```

I know I can turn it off for everything except all `IconButtons` with the following:

```
components: {
  MuiButtonBase: {
    defaultProps: {
      disableRipple: true,
      },
    },
  MuiIconButton: {
    defaultProps: {
      disableRipple: false,
    },
  },
},
```

I know I can turn it off each component individually with this JSX:

```
<Button disableRipple>
  Only one rippleless!
</Button>
```

##### But is there any way to turn the ripple off globally and just *enable* it individually?

For example, something that would do what the following fake code suggests:

```
<Button enableRipple>
  Only one rippled!
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay its this easy:

```
<Button disableRipple={false}>
  Only one rippled!
</Button>
```